# Installing Android

Tags: installation

I currently have a Samsung SM-P610 tablet running Samsung's version of Android 13. I'm tired of all the bloatware associated with it and would like to install a clean version of Android. How can I do that?

Comment: Search the net for a custom ROM you like and that is explicitly built for your phone model. Then follow the installation instructions of the custom ROM. Note that certain security and financial apps may no longer work on a custom ROM as the phone is no longer genuine (Play Integrity Check fails).

Comment: Thanks Robert. I'll do that.

Comment: Please first make yourself familiar with the selected custom ROM, the installation, the tools, pitfalls that may brick your device, features of the custom ROM that don't fully work, and what other users write about it. I would at least give this process a few weeks before actually flashing the ROM.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. I'm already investigating Lineage OS but I want something where I can still access the Play Store. However, I'd like it to be a stripped down version with just Google's native apps, for example: docs, sheets, assistant, etc.

Comment: CustomROMs with Play Services & Play Store are prohibited by Google. You always have to install Google apps and services as an additional package like opengapps or microg.